# Keeping buttons on top while content changes underneath

Tags: iphone, uibutton, scrollview

I am trying to create a view with buttons that overlay a scrollview and stay visible while the content underneath scrolls. These buttons, when pressed, will change the content underneath.

I am a fairly competent developer but need a little bit of direction with this problem, any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed the scroll view within another view, then add the button to this outer view. Add content you want to scroll to the scroll view, and the button should stay stationary.

Comment: Yep that's no problem but how can the view above change the view below?

Comment: how did you want to change the content underneath? connect the button to the outermost viewcontroller, and either swap out the scrollView content from there, or get it to pass along a call to the innerView, to make the appropriate changes.